# Extend interface with another

Tags: typescript

Basically I want to extend userinterface as shown below, is this the way to do it? everything besides the data field get's filled properly and using "UserInterface extends DataInterFace" just throws a lot of errors.

There's nothing official in the documentation about this so do any of you have an idea?

```
export interface UserInterface {
  username: string,
  firstname: string,
  lastname: string,
  data: DataInterface
}

export interface DataInterface {
  test: string,
  test2: string
}

let test = { username: "test", firstname: "test", lastname: "test", data: {
  test: "hello",
  test2: "hello2"
}};

let DoesItWork:UserInterface = <UserInterface>test;
console.log(DoesItWork);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  You're not trying to extend anything, from your code it looks like `UserInterface` contains a `DataInterface` member named `data`. Then you create an instance and assign the same one to another variable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: parse json into the interface? it's really obvious?

Comment: It really is not obvious what you're asking.

Comment: Your code basically does nothing.  You're not parsing anything here, parsing would require you to have the json as a string not as a js object.
You just create an instance of an object which matches the `UserInterface`, then you assign it to another variable and print that.

Comment: pretty much yea, problem is it doesn't work as intended. Is this not the proper way of doing it? Basically In my app I do a http request to an api and I want to assign interface's to the data so far it works except for the DataInterface, it's always null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer cuz there's no readable way to show code in comments.

Your interfaces are ok, but they have no inheritance as none of them extends the other. What you do have is composition as `UserInterface` contains `DataInterface`.

Extending would look like this:

```
interface DataInterface {
    test: string,
    test2: string
}

interface UserInterface extends DataInterface {
    username: string,
    firstname: string,
    lastname: string
}
```

An instance of UserInterface will have the `test` and `test2` members as well as the others defined in it.
But that's probably not what you want cuz it will be `user.test` instead of `user.data.test`.

As for the parsing part, that's not what you're doing. This:

```
var user: UserInterface = {
    username: "username",
    firstname: "firstname",
    lastname: "lastname"
    data: {
        test: "test",
        test2: "test2"
    }
}
```

assigns the actual object to the variable, there's no need to parse anything here, you already have the object and it's typed.

If you get the object from the server then it comes as a string, in that case you'll need to:

```
var user: UserInterface = <UserInterface> JSON.parse(USER_STRING_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Thank you, I could use the information you provided and solved it. Thank you very much